# iOS 3rd-party mail app which allows connections to multiple ports at the same time

Tags: ios, email, software-recommendation, mobile-mail

I need to travel to a country that blocks port 25 (SMTP) and 993 (IMAP) country-wide.

The stock mail.app does not allow me to specify multiple ports for both SMTP and IMAP.

Changing the port values back and forth for up to 10 email accounts is very tedious…

Does anybody know if there's a third party mail app client that allows me to specify, say, "25, 1225" and "993,9993"?

Comment: Have you thought of using a vpn?

Comment: We have full control of our mail server, so we thought it's more straightforward to go this route, instead of relying on another middle man.

Comment: It's not more straightforward to mangle all the ports, but that might be your last resort. Since I know a good vpn I'll answer. There isn't a good mail client option I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of a third party application. But besides a vpn, you could try going to settings>mail>your specific mail account. This may give you the option to change the incoming mail server, but it may not. But you can change the outgoing mail server by adding a entire new secondary server in case the first one doesn't work. You can look at the pictures attached.

[image: possibly change the incoming settings]

[image: change the outgoing settings]

Comment: Brilliant! Simple and easy! Gosh, why didn't I think of this! We can create a second account having all the same information as the original one, except the 2 port numbers!

Comment: Oh good idea! Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

A one stop fix would be to get VPN as a service to quickly fix networks that block based on ports or deeper packet inspection.

Start with this free option to be sure VPN aren't blocked too.

- TunnelBear Free VPN -
  https://appsto.re/us/R8SQH.i

The next easiest option would be to make configuration profiles to push to the devices. iOS allows easy push of mail configuration profiles to automate the tap, tap, tap, type chore of changing ports on multiple accounts. I recommend you start with a free hosted MDM that's also reputable.

- https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/ - choose the start trial

There is some setup, but if you're already running Mail servers I would expect the setup to take about 30 minutes top to be running with your push certificates, one device enrolled, and push custom mail settings to that enrolled device.

[image]

Basically, you would:

1. Sign up
2. Follow the Push Notification
3. Make a blueprint
4. Define one mail server profile like I show above
5. Enroll your device in the MDM
6. Choose the bluerint that has your mail settings
7. Profit for ever more now that you have an MDM to automate your iOS team devices.

Comment: In addition to this vpn, "X-VPN" is a good solution. It has 3 different protocols in case one is blocked.